# Adjust the position of child div relatively

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML which displays some windows with the background image in it. Every row contains some number of such windows. Now, I want a small variation in them, I want to position the 1st row 2nd window( and all windows in that row) to be positioned to the right side of the 2nd window in the 2nd row. In brief, the windows should just be shifted to right side of the 2nd window in 2nd row. I am not sure how to do that. Here is the code written in HTML & CSS as

HTML code-

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="flower chunk1">
        <div><img src="http://assets.freeprintable.com/images/item/thumb/lotus-flower.jpg"/></div></div>

        <div class="flower chunk15">
        <div><img src="http://assets.freeprintable.com/images/item/thumb/lotus-flower.jpg"/></div></div>

        <div class="flower chunk2">
        <div><img src="http://assets.freeprintable.com/images/item/thumb/lotus-flower.jpg"/></div></div>

        <div class="flower chunk3">
        <div><img src="http://assets.freeprintable.com/images/item/thumb/lotus-flower.jpg"/></div></div>

        <div class="flower chunk4">
        <div><img src="http://assets.freeprintable.com/images/item/thumb/lotus-flower.jpg"/></div></div>
    </div>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="flower chunk5">
        <div><img src="http://assets.freeprintable.com/images/item/thumb/lotus-flower.jpg"/></div></div>

        <div class="flower chunk6">
        <div><img src="http://assets.freeprintable.com/images/item/thumb/lotus-flower.jpg"/></div></div>

        <div class="flower chunk7">
        <div><img src="http://assets.freeprintable.com/images/item/thumb/lotus-flower.jpg"/></div></div>

        <div class="flower chunk8">
        <div><img src="http://assets.freeprintable.com/images/item/thumb/lotus-flower.jpg"/></div></div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="flower chunk9">
        <div><img src="http://assets.freeprintable.com/images/item/thumb/lotus-flower.jpg"/></div></div>

        <div class="flower chunk10">
        <div><img src="http://assets.freeprintable.com/images/item/thumb/lotus-flower.jpg"/></div></div>

        <div class="flower chunk11">
        <div><img src="http://assets.freeprintable.com/images/item/thumb/lotus-flower.jpg"/></div></div>

        <div class="flower chunk12">
        <div><img src="http://assets.freeprintable.com/images/item/thumb/lotus-flower.jpg"/></div></div>
    </div>
```

CSS code-

```
    .container {
        float: left;
        white-space: nowrap;

    }
    .flower {
        display: inline;
        float: left;
        margin: 10px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    .flower img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .flower div {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .chunk2 div {
        left: -100px;
    }
    .chunk3 div {
        top: -100px;
    }
    .chunk4 div {
        top: -100px;
        left: -100px;
    }
```

Here is the jsFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/VSd6Y/16/
Please let me know what should i do to shift the windows in the same row.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want there to be animation?  What user event triggers the shift?  Drag and drop?

Comment: No. The event is the dependency between them. So if the window1 in row 1 is dependent on window 2 on row 2, then the window1 in row1 should appear after window2 in row 2.

Comment: @Dave: Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is what you're looking for.  Please let me know if it is and I will update my answer to explain what I changed and why.

http://jsfiddle.net/VSd6Y/17/

Comment: Yes this is something I want. In my actual working code, I dont have top & left specified. Everything is positioned relatively and with the float:left. So is there any other way I can set this except specifying the left. As well I am using the margin but the problem is the margin is set same to every window so I am not able to identify which window is placed first. Thanks for the answer though